# Error while coping a file to server machine from local machine in windows application setup

Tags: .net, io, installation, file-copying

I'm developing a application in which a .mdf file should get copied to the server machine where the MSSQL server is installed.
Code :

```
// for simplicity here i just put the hard coded server path in actual application i getting that programmatically.
string serverPath = "\\\\serverName\\C$\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL.1\\MSSQL\\Data";
byte[] buff = null;
buff = Properties.Resources.SomeResourceFile1;
File.WriteAllBytes(serverPath + "\\" + mdfNewFileName, buff);
buff = null;
buff = Properties.Resources.SomeResourceFile2;
File.WriteAllBytes(serverPath + "\\" + ldfNewFileName, buff);
```

In the above code I am getting Access Denied! error, this is because of I may have not full access over that folder. So that first I changed the access of that folder by following code :

```
DirectorySecurity sec = Directory.GetAccessControl(serverPath);
SecurityIdentifier everyone = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null);
sec.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(everyone, FileSystemRights.Modify | FileSystemRights.Synchronize, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow));
Directory.SetAccessControl(serverPath, sec);
```

Now I am getting "unauthorized operation exception ".
Above both mentioned exception are coming only from the **application setup**, if I debug from the VS2010 then its working fine but when I create setup of that application then I am getting that exception.

Comment: try to run as administrator.

Comment: @ Nimesh : i am running the application as administrator but am not administrator on server machine where sql server is installed.

Comment: Have you tried Right Click on Application and Click on Run as.. if it is not working then you have to add permission manually in server computer for that shared folder..

Comment: that's what i am asking , whether it is possible by programmatically change the server folder permission to Everyone ?

Comment: this can be done only when your application is executed on server computer with administrator privilege.(Run as.. Administrator).

Comment: @nimesh : but above code is working fine when I debug that from VS2010 ,the error comes only when I create a setup for that application & execute.

Comment: I agree with you, I think also the problem is in user permission for shared folder. the folder might be fully accessible for administrator only.but, for other user it is read only. do you have tried to copy mdf file manually into that folder. just copy and paste. When your project is in debug mode it may use the administrator permission .